# Using Heritrix 1.14

Tags: unix, shell, installation

Went through the post and your suggested solution as in --
[Which web crawler for extracting and parsing data from about a thousand of web sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653749/which-web-crawler-for-extracting-and-parsing-data-from-about-a-thousand-of-web-si)

Have installed heritrix under /root/heritrix-1.14.4

Stuck at export HERITRIX_HOME=/PATH/TO/BUILT/HERITRIX .

The command runs silently, but cd $heritrix_home results in

-bash: cd: /root/heritrix-1.14.4/bin/heritrix: Not a directory.

Have googled unsuccessfully.

chmod u+x $heritrix_home/bin/heritrix results in
chmod: cannot access `/root/heritrix-1.14.4/bin/heritrix/bin/heritrix': Not a directory

Your valuable guidance / pointers requested

Comment: I doubt that it's a good idea to install into root's home directory. A better place would be /usr/local/heritrix. A hope you do not run it as root (unless absolutely necessary).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like HERITRIX_HOME is set to /root/heritrix-1.14.4/bin/heritrix where it should be set to the directory /root/heritrix-1.14.4